# Add service reference generated my client incompelety

Tags: c#, wcf

Something has gone wrong when I "Add Service Reference" to target my wcf.

I target my wcf and clicked OK. You get after OK normally a nice generated files like Reference.cs (client). I see know that Reference.cs is incompeletely generated. See below:

```
namespace WindowsPhoneApp.ServiceReference1 {
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="AlgemeenKlassementJSON", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfOpzet.jsonModels")]
    public partial class AlgemeenKlassementJSON : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private long idField;

        private long puntenField;

        private string rennersField;

        private long rondesField;

        private long teamnrField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public long id {
            get {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set {
                if ((this.idField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.idField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("id");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public long punten {
            get {
                return this.puntenField;
            }
            set {
                if ((this.puntenField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.puntenField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("punten");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string renners {
            get {
                return this.rennersField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.rennersField, value) != true)) {
                    this.rennersField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("renners");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public long rondes {
            get {
                return this.rondesField;
            }
            set {
                if ((this.rondesField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.rondesField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("rondes");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public long teamnr {
            get {
                return this.teamnrField;
            }
            set {
                if ((this.teamnrField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.teamnrField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("teamnr");
                }
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="TeamsJSON", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfOpzet.jsonModels")]
    public partial class TeamsJSON : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private WindowsPhoneApp.ServiceReference1.Image fotorennerAField;

        private byte[] fotorennerBField;

        private long idField;

        private byte[] landrennerAField;

        private byte[] landrennerBField;

        private string rennerAField;

        private string rennerBField;

        private string teamNaamField;

        private byte[] teamShirtField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public WindowsPhoneApp.ServiceReference1.Image fotorennerA {
            get {
                return this.fotorennerAField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.fotorennerAField, value) != true)) {
                    this.fotorennerAField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("fotorennerA");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public byte[] fotorennerB {
            get {
                return this.fotorennerBField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.fotorennerBField, value) != true)) {
                    this.fotorennerBField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("fotorennerB");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public long id {
            get {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set {
                if ((this.idField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.idField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("id");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public byte[] landrennerA {
            get {
                return this.landrennerAField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.landrennerAField, value) != true)) {
                    this.landrennerAField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("landrennerA");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public byte[] landrennerB {
            get {
                return this.landrennerBField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.landrennerBField, value) != true)) {
                    this.landrennerBField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("landrennerB");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string rennerA {
            get {
                return this.rennerAField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.rennerAField, value) != true)) {
                    this.rennerAField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("rennerA");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string rennerB {
            get {
                return this.rennerBField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.rennerBField, value) != true)) {
                    this.rennerBField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("rennerB");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string teamNaam {
            get {
                return this.teamNaamField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.teamNaamField, value) != true)) {
                    this.teamNaamField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("teamNaam");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public byte[] teamShirt {
            get {
                return this.teamShirtField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.teamShirtField, value) != true)) {
                    this.teamShirtField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("teamShirt");
                }
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    public class Image {

**Incomplete!**
    }
**Incomplete! I miss my operations of my wcf**
}
```

Here an image where my problem is started. (Need at least 10 rept points, no images :D)

Comment: Did you check on the WCF side if you correctly put the [OperationContract] on the missing methods (defined in the interface) ?

Comment: Can't you just "Update service reference" through Visual studio?

Comment: @Fabske [OperationContract] also on the missing methods.

Comment: @Serge Did Update Service Reference, same problem.

Comment: @Sigfrid And are you sure you put the method (with OperationContract attribute) in the WCF Interface as well before rebuilding it?

Comment: Did you try accessing its WSDL/mex on http? @Sigfrid

Comment: Yes everything works, my wsdl file is 100% working if i test on browser, i get my data from my operations. It's something with generation. It generates not completely, something is disturbing the generation.

Comment: Are you sure the client proxy project target the correct URL ? Because if you use svn and make some branches, your project may connect to an url not for current branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use non-seriazable types that the datacontractserializer can't handle such as System.drawing.